# Is it normal for Black Haus Blackberry Schnapps to taste like acetone?

Tags: taste, spirits

I have consumed very little alcohol in the last 20 or so years, so my taste-buds and tolerance are like a young person.

Someone gave me a bottle of Black Haus. It has a nice blackberry flavor, but there is a strong odor that strikes my nose and tongue like acetone (nail polish remover). Is this normal for this spirit? Is it safe to drink (sip)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain spoilage bacteria can give an acetone like flavor. I’ve personally had a batch of homemade wine turn out with this flavor after being improperly sanitized beforehand. However, the wine itself was perfectly safe to drink, and I’ve gone though many bottles of it no problem. In my experience, most liquors simply get a bad taste when they spoil, and aren’t actually unsafe to drink due to the high alcohol content. Of course I can’t tell you 100% if it’s safe to drink, butch it was freshly opened, it’s likely just the way the liquor tastes. And if not, even then, it still likely won’t make you sick, just have an off flavor.

Comment: I'm thinking "butch it was freshly opened" isn't what you meant to write. Maybe "but if it was freshly opened"?

Comment: We ended up discarding it because of the "off" flavor. May try it again sometime.